# Image processing algorithme idea - Opencv

Tags: c++, image, algorithm, opencv

I'm trying to isolate little object (black objects) in semolina like the image below. I use OpenCV 3.1 in C++.

I try different method and the best that I found is below. But the result is not good as I want.
I only want to have my black objects at the final.

### Original Image :

[image: Original Image of semolina]

So I convert my image to grayscale, and apply GaussianBlur and a large Blur in order to have a background.

```
GaussianBlur(img_gray, img_inter, Size(21, 21), 0, 0);
blur(img_inter, img_blur, Size(51, 51), Point(-1,-1), 0);
```

### Background Image :

[image: Background Image]

After, I subtract my background to my original image:

### Subtracted Image :

[image: Subtracted Image]

And the final image after opening operation, threshold and opening again :

### Result Image :

[image: Final Image]

The code below :

```
cvtColor(*img_in, img_gray, CV_BayerGB2GRAY);

GaussianBlur(img_gray, img_inter, Size(21, 21), 0, 0);

blur(img_inter, img_blur, Size(51, 51), Point(-1,-1), 0);

img = (255 - img_gray) - (255 - img_blur); // Background subtraction

morphologyEx(img, img_inter, cv::MORPH_OPEN, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(3, 3)),Point(-1,-1), 1);
threshold(img_inter, img, 50, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY);
morphologyEx(img, img_inter, cv::MORPH_OPEN, cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(3, 3)), Point(-1, -1), 1);
```

If you have any ideas to improve the result, thanks you

Comment: Hey there. The general methods looks good already. What are you after exactly, improvements? Just warning you since you are new, but you are very likely to get your question closed because it does not have an exact answer.

Comment: Are the black objects always in this kind of configuration? (at the top, flat) If so, you could get some good results with some patterns matching too maybe?

Comment: Thank you jlengrand, yes my objects are almost always like this. I want to keep processing simple because I need good output fps. In the final image there are some noisy point that I don't want and I'm not able to remove them without removing good one.

Comment: Well, you can make pattern matching as simple as you want. By the look of it, the objects you are searching for are long, thin and black. So with the  final output you have now, I would try to compare against the original image color and see if it matches a black thing, try to see how long is the object and it that matches the usual size of the residuals (it should remove most of your small points), and maybe have a thinness/length check and make some kind of score out of those elements for each object. That should be quick :).

Comment: instead of blurring sharpen the image and then try again.